# how should I respond to a poorly asked question that I incorrectly answered?

Tags: discussion

Sorry about the poor title, but it is hard to phrase as a title.  Anyway, I was hanging around the newly asked question area, trying to make myself useful, when I came across this question:

[How can i make it draw a rectangle with dots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334944/how-can-i-make-it-draw-a-rectangle-with-dots/29335118#29335118)

If you looked at it before the edit, you'd probably make the same mistake I did. I thought that the asker was simply asking how to print a set rectangle, however, he wanted a rectangle that the user could change the dimensions of.  As I had false information, I incorrectly answered the question, and in a course of 30 seconds, I had received 2 down votes.

I deleted the answer, but would like to know what to do in the future.

Comment: You did the right thing deleting your answer. Even for the first revision of the question it seems not to fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I could suggest you is,

- read the question carefully
- If you are not clear or you need more
  information, put a comment to the user asking more information
- after getting more clues, if you feel the question is correct and you can answer it, then go for it.
- if that question is related to your expertise area and you feel something not correct in the question, you could edit the question. if that edit is correct, the asker will accept it.

What you have done now is (deleting the answer) correct as it might mislead the other users who seeks the same help!
Anyway, please read the stackoverflow user guide carefully.

hope this helps you to get an idea on future usage.